# mvc-pdf not opening in mobile browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, object, pdf

I am using object to render my pdf it works fine on desktop browsers but on mobile browsers its not opening up pdf file,it says pdf reader not supported on this device.I have tried using embed also but it didn't worked out.

view

```
 <object type="application/pdf"
                    data="@Url.Content(Model.ReportUrl)"
                    width="100%" height="100%">PDF reader not supported for this device.
            </object>

  //tried these also
    @*<object type="application/pdf"
                    data="@Url.Content(Model.ReportUrl)"
                    width="100%" height="100%">PDF reader not supported for this device.
            <a href="@Url.Content(Model.ReportUrl)"></a></object>*@

      @*<object type="application/pdf"
                    data="@Url.Content(Model.ReportUrl)"
                    width="100%" height="100%">PDF reader not supported for this device.
            <embed src="@Url.Content(Model.ReportUrl)" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" /> </object>*@
```

I tried searching but not able to find any useful result.

Answer (score 1):

On my phone, when I click on a PDF link it will launch an external PDF viewer. The built in browser doesn't have a plug-in that can process PDFs so it is handled externally. I believe this is done because on the desktop these plug-ins are a major source of security vulnerabilities.

Trying to embed the PDF into a page on the browser may not be viable.
You may want to try browsing to other sites that embed PDFs to determine if your device can do this.

If not, there are things you can do to improve the user experience.
On some sites when it downloads the PDF it ends up in my downloads directory. I then have to go find it and click on it to view it. On other sites I automatically get a dialog asking me what app I want to use to view the PDF as soon as it is downloaded.

Comment: but when you view any pdf on some website it is viewed inside browser only how it is done then?

Comment: On your desktop browser if you go to Tools/Options - Programs/Plugins (depends on browser) you will see that it is using the Adobe Reader plugin to display PDF files within the browser. Adobe is notorious for writing vulnerable software. Google/Android & Apple won't allow Adobe plugins to run inside the browsers on their devices. Therefore, the PDF cannot be rendered. Try the link below. On my desktop browser I see the PDF displayed properly. On my phone it downloads the file.

http://www.planetpdf.com/planetpdf/pdfs/gkent/example1.pdf